# "LimitException: Batchable instance is too big" when scheduled batch runs at night

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, platform-bug, limitexception

***Note: This is not a duplicate of the other similar questions. We checked them before. So please don't close this as a duplicate!***

When calling this batch class in a production org:

```
global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{

    global Set<Id> contactIds;
    global String query;


    global MyBatch (Set<Id> contactIds) {
        this.contactIds = contactIds;
        this.query = 'SELECT Id from Package_Contact__c WHERE ID IN :contactIds';
    }


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        System.debug(scope);
        try {
            delete scope;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {

    }
}
```

from this scheduled class directly via the `DevConsole`

```
global class MyScheduled implements Schedulable {

    ...


    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(fourThousandIDS));
    }

    ...
}
```

everything runs fine.

**But** when we call this class scheduled each night it fails with

> LimitException: Batchable instance is too big

This must be a server thing or a **platform bug** newly introduced.

Comment: I already open a support case #25486871 for that.

Comment: Can you add exactly how you are invoking it in the Dev Console? Is it by "new MyScheduled(someListOfIds).execute(null);"?

Comment: @PhilW Yes we ran with new MyScheduled().execute(null);

Comment: So how is the list of IDs "fourThousandIDS" initialized? Could this be the source of the issue?

Comment: @PhilW Oh you mean the error happens even before the batch runs?! But why does it not fail when called from dev console

Comment: What I wonder about is whether the list of IDs is actually generated the same in both cases. For example, perhaps you have sharing rules that limit the list length in the dev console, but the usage in production actually gets a different list that is longer?

Comment: @PhilW we know that the amount of ids is always 4000. we See 20 batch jobs. Therefore I think the init code cannot be the problem. Not the scheduling fails but the batch run.

Comment: OK, if you are 100% sure. It seems like there is too much [state held in your Batchable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319198&type=1&mode=1) and that the instantiation context causes this to vary significantly. Do you hold any other state than the list of IDs and the query?

Comment: @PhilW No we don't have anything other than the list of Ids and the query.

Comment: Hi Robert, did you find the cause of this ? cc @dennisjsk